# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'GameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your answers!

I am a beginner in unity, coding my second game after i finshed a couple of tutorials.
Since today, i noticed that suddenly all my "GameObjects" have a "UnityEngine." in front of them.

I have no idea how that happened, and it is also not just in one script, but all of them. Heres an example of it:

```
UnityEngine.GameObject item = (UnityEngine.GameObject)Instantiate(itemGOList[i], spawnTransform, spawnRotation);
```

This worked fine before without the "UnityEngine.", but now it only works when its written this way.

Do you know how this could have happened and how to revert it?

This is one of the scripts:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform target;
    private Enemy targetEnemy;

    [Header("General")]

    public float range = 10f;

    [Header("Use Bullets/missiles (default)")]
    public UnityEngine.GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    private float fireCountdown = 0f;

    public AudioClip shootingSound;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    [Header("Use Laser (default)")]
    public bool useLaser = false;

    public int damageOverTime = 20;

    public float slowAmount = .5f;

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public ParticleSystem impactEffect;
    public Light impactLight;

    [Header("Unity Setup Fields")]


    public string enemyTag = "Enemy";

    public Transform partToRotate;
    public float turnSpeed = 10f;

    public Transform firePoint;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(UpdateTarget), 0f, 0.3f); // Call the UpdateTarget Method after 0 seconds, then repeat every 0.3 seconds.
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); //Puts the AudioSource of this GO (the turret) into the variable audioSource.
    }

    void UpdateTarget ()
    {
        UnityEngine.GameObject[] enemies = UnityEngine.GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(enemyTag); // Find all enemies (and store in a list?).
        float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity; // Create a float for the shortest distance to an enemy.
        UnityEngine.GameObject nearestEnemy = null; // Create a variable which stores the nearest enemy as a gameobject.

        foreach (UnityEngine.GameObject enemy in enemies) // Loop through the enemies array.
        {
            float distanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position); //Get the distance to each enemy and stores it.
            if (distanceToEnemy < shortestDistance) // If any of the enemies is closer than the original, make this distance the new shortestDistance and the new enemy to the nearestEnemy.
            {
                shortestDistance = distanceToEnemy;
                nearestEnemy = enemy;
            }
        }
        if (nearestEnemy != null && shortestDistance <= range) // Sets the target to the nearestEnemy (only if its in range and not null).
        {
            target = nearestEnemy.transform;
            targetEnemy = nearestEnemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        }
        else
        {
            target = null;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
            if (target == null) // If there is no target, do nothing.
        {
            if (useLaser)
            {
                if (lineRenderer.enabled)
                {
                    lineRenderer.enabled = false;
                    impactEffect.Stop();
                    impactLight.enabled = false;
                    audioSource.Stop();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        LockOnTarget();

        if (useLaser)
        {
            Laser();
        }
        else
        {
            if (fireCountdown <= 0f)
            {
                Shoot();
                fireCountdown = 1f / fireRate;
            }

            fireCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        
    }

    void Laser()
    {
        targetEnemy.TakeDamage(damageOverTime * Time.deltaTime);
        targetEnemy.Slow(slowAmount);

        if (!lineRenderer.enabled)
        {
            lineRenderer.enabled = true;
            impactEffect.Play();
            impactLight.enabled = true;
            if (audioSource.isPlaying == false)
            {
                audioSource.Play();
            }
        }
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, firePoint.position);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, target.position);

        Vector3 dir = firePoint.position - target.position;

        impactEffect.transform.position = target.position + dir.normalized * 1f;

        impactEffect.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    }

    void LockOnTarget()
    {
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position; // Store the direction from turret to target.
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir); // I have no idea how this works...
        Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(partToRotate.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed).eulerAngles; // Convert quaternion angles to euler angles and Lerp it (smoothing out the transition).
        partToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation.y, 0f); // Only rotate around the y-axis.
    }
    
    void Shoot()
    {
        UnityEngine.GameObject bulletGO = (UnityEngine.GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation); // Spawn a bullet at the location and rotation of firePoint. (Also makes this a GO to reference it.
        Bullet bullet = bulletGO.GetComponent<Bullet>(); // I have no idea how this works...
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(shootingSound, 0.2f);


        if (bullet != null) // If there is a bullet, use the seek method from the bullet script.
        {
            bullet.Seek(target);
        }

    }
    void OnDrawGizmosSelected() // Do this method if gizmo is selected.
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range); // Draw a wire sphere on the selected point (selected turret f. e.) and give it the towers range.
    }

   
}
```

Comment: 'unityengine' is part of the namespace, do you have a second class named exactly the same, `GameObject` in your project somewhere? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/ The namespace is added before the class to make it more specific. I.e. if i have `MyNamespace.MyClass` and `OtherNamespace.MyClass` - I need to add the namespace when using `MyClass` so the compiler knows which `MyClass` i mean.

Comment: Did you create your own type called `GameObject`? Go into Unity and in the ProjectView search for `GameObject`

Comment: Thats it, thanks a bunch! I have no idea why, but one of the scripts is suddenly called GameObject. Deleted it, now how can i revert all the UnityEngine.GameObject to Gameobject?
Also, how can i mark this answer as the best answer?

Comment: Okay got it, i figured out i could just let visual studio edit all the UnityEngine.GameObjects for me in the whole project!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that i had a script called "GameObject" in my Unity Project.

I was also able to rename all "UnityEngine.GameObject" to "Gameobject" by using the Quick Action in Visual Studio.